# How to Test windows Phone app 8.1 without stimulator?

Tags: windows-phone-8

"  I am going to develop one Windows Phone APP 8.1 , I am having core2dual processor, I am trying to install stimulator but it is not installing"
    is there any other way to test mobile application?

Comment: You can go to site www.dvlup.com and get some devices for testing remotely too. You can also request some test devices. (the new name of the site is https://rewards.msdn.microsoft.com/)

Comment: @kanchirk they will provide device for Windows or Android and iOS also?

Comment: AFAIK Windows Phone devices.. am not sure about Android/IOS.

Comment: @kanchirk How do I test my code there or how do I proceed?

Comment: First Register as a windows Phone developer on the https://dev.windows.com/en-US/ site. Then use that account to visit rewards.msdn.microsoft.com and gain some points solving some quiz and use those points to request a device. Alternatively read this https://developer.coronalabs.com/forum/2011/06/23/remote-application-testing-multiple-actual-devices-without-buying-them  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13525256/remote-test-laboratory-for-mobile-app-testing

Comment: @kanchirk ok I got it. Happy Coding :)

Comment: @kanchirk Is it necessary to paid money for developer account ?

Comment: Windows Phone Developer account is free to signup for.